# Dimensions of non square matrix?

Tags: matrices, self-learning, orthonormal, gram-schmidt

After performing Gram-Schmidt process for the following matrix:

$\pmatrix{3&2&3\\ 2&5&-1\\ 2&4&8\\ 12&2&1}$

the resultant matrix is this one:

$\pmatrix{0.23643312&0.18771349&0.22132104\\  0.15762208&0.74769023&-0.64395812\\ 0.15762208&0.57790444&0.72904263\\ 0.94573249&-0.26786082&-0.06951101}$

I wonder why the last row of the above orthonormal matrix is not a zero vector? And what is more strange is that its dimensions(sum of all the norms) is 3. How can those three (column) vectors be in space? Is the space three-dimensional or four-dimensional?

Comment: Each of the column vectors is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^4$. The span of the columns forms a $3$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$. If I am understanding correctly what seems to be confusing you is how a $3$ dimensional subspace can have non-zero entries in each coordinate, to answer this think about the toy example of the span of $(1,1)^T$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, this is the "$y = x$" line which is a $1$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, but you have non-zero entries in both coordinates.

Comment: @Dylan How about performing some operations for rows to make one row a zero vector?

Comment: So one of many great things about Gram Schmidt is that the column space (i.e. span of the column vectors) is the same before and after applying the process. So there is nothing stopping you applying some row operations to zero the final row, however you will lose orthogonality of rows, and you will change the column space, although you will preserve the column rank, but overall this is not something you want to do.